# Error while trying to get access to google.com for my local web application

Tags: php, email, web-applications, gmail, phpmailer

I hope someone of you can give me some helpful instructions about this problem! I'm getting mad!
The fact is this:
I would like to send emails by my local web application using Google SMTP. I created a .json file in the root folder of my application like this:

```
{
"require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
    "league/oauth2-client": "^1.0"
}}
```

In order to download and install by compiler the PHPMailer and the oauth2client that is needed.
Then I created a new project in the [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) and I configured it: I enabled gmail API, obtained the correct credentials (ID and SECRET) and set the authorized direct URI like this:

```
http://localhost/folder1/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/get_oauth_token.php
```

Now I edited the get_oauth_token.php with the obtained credentials, but then when I try to insert the previous URI in the browser to get the permissions an errror is occurring:

> **Fatal error**: Class 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google' not found in **C:\xampp\htdocs\folder1\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\get_oauth_token.php** on line 28

And i can't go on.. I tried to send and email with a main php script but obviously i can't get access and my request is refused by the server. Any suggestions?
Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

had the exact same problem.  what i did was to install:

```
composer require league/oauth2-google
```

and the problem dissapear

;)

Answer (score 2):

The PHPMailer `composer.json` can't require the league OAuth2 packages by default for 2 reasons:

- They will break on PHP versions < 5.4 and the rest of PHPMailer supports back to 5.0
- Not everyone needs them.

For these reasons they are in the 'suggests' section of the composer.json, so you will need to manually require them for your project. Do that, and the autoloader will be able to find them.

Comment: Which files should I require? And Should I require them into the get_oauth_token.php? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the lines in the `suggest` section of PHPMailer's `composer.json`, add them to the `requires` section of your own `composer.json`, then `composer install` and it will install all the libs you need, and all you need is the normal composer autoloader.

Comment: I wrote at the beginning the two strings in my .json file about `league/oauth2-client` and the `phpmailer` in the require section and i already composer installed them. I included the path of the  `autload.php` created by the composer. I tryed to upgrade and try to recompose but it tells me there's nothing to install or to upgrade.