# Server returns 500 error on phpmailer get outh token file

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer, http-status-code-500

When I try to access `phpmailer/get_outh_token.php` to get `refresh token` server returns:

> HTTP ERROR 500

`Client ID`, `Secret key` and `redirect Uri` are correct, and i am using it already in `Wordpress`.

I have downloaded last version of `phpmailer`, also tested with old version with same result.

I found what cause this, it is this part:

```
namespace League\OAuth2\Client\Provider;
```

When I remove it, then script loads with errors of course because

> Provider namespace is not loaded.

Website working on `PHP 7.`

This is full code of `get_outh_token.php`, and it is original (just credentials are different of course):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
/**
 * Get an OAuth2 token from Google.
 * * Install this script on your server so that it's accessible
 * as [https/http]://<yourdomain>/<folder>/get_oauth_token.php
 * e.g.: http://localhost/phpmail/get_oauth_token.php
 * * Ensure dependencies are installed with 'composer install'
 * * Set up an app in your Google developer console
 * * Set the script address as the app's redirect URL
 * If no refresh token is obtained when running this file, revoke access to your app
 * using link: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens and run the script again.
 * This script requires PHP 5.4 or later
 * PHP Version 5.4
 */

namespace League\OAuth2\Client\Provider; //when i remove this line, than page load without 500, but with errors.

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Tool\BearerAuthorizationTrait;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

session_start();

//If this automatic URL doesn't work, set it yourself manually
$redirectUri = 'https://www.secret.co/phpmailer/get_oauth_token.php';

//These details obtained are by setting up app in Google developer console.
$clientId = 'secret.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$clientSecret = 'secret';

class Google extends AbstractProvider
{
    use BearerAuthorizationTrait;

    const ACCESS_TOKEN_RESOURCE_OWNER_ID = 'id';

    /**
     * @var string If set, this will be sent to google as the "access_type" parameter.
     * @link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline
     */
    protected $accessType;

    /**
     * @var string If set, this will be sent to google as the "hd" parameter.
     * @link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#hd-param
     */
    protected $hostedDomain;

    /**
     * @var string If set, this will be sent to google as the "scope" parameter.
     * @link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes
     */
    protected $scope;

    public function getBaseAuthorizationUrl()
    {
        return 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';
    }

    public function getBaseAccessTokenUrl(array $params)
    {
        return 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    }

    public function getResourceOwnerDetailsUrl(AccessToken $token)
    {
    return ' ';
    }

    protected function getAuthorizationParameters(array $options)
    {
    if (is_array($this->scope)) {
            $separator = $this->getScopeSeparator();
            $this->scope = implode($separator, $this->scope);
        }

        $params = array_merge(
            parent::getAuthorizationParameters($options),
            array_filter([
                'hd'          => $this->hostedDomain,
                'access_type' => $this->accessType,
        'scope'       => $this->scope,
                // if the user is logged in with more than one account ask which one to use for the login!
                'authuser'    => '-1'
            ])
        );
        return $params;
    }

    protected function getDefaultScopes()
    {
        return [
            'email',
            'openid',
            'profile',
        ];
    }

    protected function getScopeSeparator()
    {
        return ' ';
    }

    protected function checkResponse(ResponseInterface $response, $data)
    {
        if (!empty($data['error'])) {
            $code  = 0;
            $error = $data['error'];

            if (is_array($error)) {
                $code  = $error['code'];
                $error = $error['message'];
            }

            throw new IdentityProviderException($error, $code, $data);
        }
    }

    protected function createResourceOwner(array $response, AccessToken $token)
    {
        return new GoogleUser($response);
    }
}


//Set Redirect URI in Developer Console as [https/http]://<yourdomain>/<folder>/get_oauth_token.php

$provider = new Google(
    array(
        'clientId' => $clientId,
        'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
        'redirectUri' => $redirectUri,
        'scope' => array('https://mail.google.com/'),
    'accessType' => 'offline'
    )
);

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit;
// Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state');
} else {
    // Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken(
        'authorization_code',
        array(
            'code' => $_GET['code']
        )
    );

    // Use this to get a new access token if the old one expires
    echo 'Refresh Token: ' . $token->getRefreshToken();
}
```

Comment: you should remove that `namespace` line. theres no need for it. also your stateful variables have incorrect values. it looks like you copy and pasted this code and did not read it. Also why are you starting a session at the top of a file? You should start a session only after something occurs i.e. in a function. The comments don't help either, they basically say the same thing the code does...except the code is much easier to read.

Comment: @Rafael This is original phpmailer get_oauth_token.php file from last phpmailer, i just paste my credentials there.

Comment: @Rafael When i remove it, then i get:


Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/xx/zzazfhvsnt/public_html/phpmailer/get_oauth_token.php on line 20

Comment: @Rafael Do i need to install phpmailer with composer?

Comment: I am not sure of your setup or what frameworks you are using. If you are not using a framework and just writing a simple mail program that connects to google. I would use `lusitanian/oauth` and `phpmailer/phpmailer`. The oauth library has a google implementation already. Composer will take care of the autoloading for you too. But thats what I would do.

Comment: [google oauth example using lusitanian/oauth](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib/blob/master/examples/google.php) it only takes about 10 lines of code and you should be up and running.

Comment: You don't *have* to install PHPMailer using composer, but it makes things much simpler when you start adding dependencies that have large numbers of sub-dependencies, as the league packages do. PHPMailer only works with the league auth packages; other implementations will not work, at least not without significant rework, which would defeat the whole point of using libraries at all.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I was having same issue.
All I did was to install league/oauth2-google via composer

```
composer require league/oauth2-google
```

[This helped me figure it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013008/error-while-trying-to-get-access-to-google-com-for-my-local-web-application)

Hope it help some else.